# Where can I find examples of code (of interpreter) that builds high level language control flow? (if/else, while)

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, interpreter

I know this isn't the well received kind of question usually, however it is specific and something many should benefit from.

I am studying interpreters, and have had looks at PHPs, Golangs, and Swifts source code on GitHub. They are huge repositories, and I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction of code that actually designs and parses control flow statements like loops, conditions, etc. More simplified examples would be appreciated too. Generally, how does it work?

Comment: Get a good book about compiler and interpreter theory and practice. The ["Dragon" book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) is highly recommended. Also try to find some smaller languages and study them, there are thousands available all over the Internet.

Comment: Before the Dragon Book, read [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/). After the Dragon Book, read [Lisp in Small Pieces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of examples illustrated with pseudo-code in a language that I am inventing on the fly. I hope you'll be able to follow along.

Loop example:

Source code:

```
while (SomeExpression) do
{
  OtherFunction();
}
```

Abstract syntax tree (excerpt):

```
WHILENODE:
- LoopExpression
- LoopBody
```

Compiler excerpt (output is assumed to be some sort abstract stack machine intermediate form):

```
LoopTopLabel = AllocateLabel; // Allocates a symbolic jump target, 
                              // does not assign its address,
                              // does not cause code to be emitted.
TerminationLabel = AllocateLabel; // ditto
AssignLabel(LoopTopLabel); // assigns the current code position to the label 
Emit LoopExpression; // emit the code to validate loop termination 
                     // when executed, the expression leaves its result on the
                     // top of the stack
Emit JumpIfFalse TerminationLabel; // pop loop result, branch if false
Emit LoopBody;                     // the body of the loop
Emit Jump LoopTopLabel;            // jump back to start of loop
AssignLabel(TerminationLabel);     // loop ends here
```

Resulting code:

```
    @1:
        call SomeExpression
        jmpfalse @2
        call OtherFunction
        jmp @1
    @2:
```

Condition example:

Source code:

```
if (SomeExpression)
{
    SomeFunction();
}
else
{
    OtherFunction();
}
```

Abstract syntax tree (excerpt):

```
IFNODE:
- ConditionExpression
- TrueBody
- FalseBody
```

Compiler excerpt:

```
DoneLabel = AllocateLabel;                                                            
ElseLabel = AllocateLabel;
Emit ConditionExpression; 
Emit JumpIfFalse ElseLabel;
Emit TrueBody; 
Emit Jump DoneLabel; 
AssignLabel(ElseLabel); 
Emit FalseBody; 
AssignLabel(DoneLabel);
```

Result code:

```
    call SomeExpression
    jmpfalse @1
    call SomeFunction
    jmp @2
@1:
    call OtherFunction
@2:
```

I hope this helps